# XElement.Save causes XmlUtf8RawTextWriter to throw an exception

Tags: c#, xml, exception, .net-3.5, xelement

The following exception was reported to have occurred on a client's machine:

```
System.ArgumentException: '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character.
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Byte* pDst, Boolean entitize)
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
at System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(XElement e)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Save(XmlWriter writer)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Save(String fileName, SaveOptions options)
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Save(String fileName)
```

Unfortunately, no more information is available.

The error is a bit baffling.

`0x1F` is a question mark. If a question mark was included in the name of some element or attribute (which is illegal), an exception would be thrown at creating an `XElement` or an `XAttribute` with an invalid name rather than at the moment of saving to disk.

The exception was thrown by `XmlUtf8RawTextWriter` class which is what `XElement` uses internally I guess (the application doesn't). Can't `XElement` be expected to handle coding issues etc. by itself? What could have caused it to crash? Is it some OS or framework incompatibility?

I understand my question is rather vague, but I must operate on limited information.

I'd appreciate if someone could at least point me in right direction.  I haven't seen an error like this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+001F isn't *actually* a question mark - it's a control character ("information separator one") which isn't permitted in XML. (U+003F is a question mark.)

Basically you've got an invalid character in your `XElement`, which can't be correctly persisted. It's not clear where you're getting your data from, but that's the problem. You'll need to work out what to do with the bad data - whether to just remove it entirely, escape it somehow or whatever.

Here's a short but complete program which will reproduce the problem though, if it helps:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var element = new XElement("foo", "\u001f");
        element.Save(new MemoryStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But doesn't `XElement` automatically escape characters that need to be escaped (such as ampersands etc.), or wrap them in a CDATA block? How does one sanitize the contents of `XElement` "manually"?

Comment: @Morawski: No - you simply can't represent those characters directly in XML, not even in CDATA. To sanitize, you'd want to write a method which checked whether the content contained any invalid characters, and did a replace if so. (A regex replace *may* end up being the fastest approach.) I'd do it on the way in if I were you though, before it's in an XElement.